# Need help for mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

First three queries are working fine but the last on is not. The 2nd query is working alright with the `$status !== ''`  but last one have the same `$status !== ''`  is not executing query can any one help me out

```
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {

     $status = $_POST[status];
     if ($status == 4){
             $status = '' ;
     }

    if ($topic == 100 && $subtopic == '' && $status == '' ) {
    $queryString = "select * from tblquiz where userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]' LIMIT $start, $limit" ;
    $countString = "select * from tblquiz where userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]'";
    }  // NOTE : THIS QUERY IS WORKING PERFECT

       elseif ($topic !== '' && $subtopic !== '' && $status !== '' ) {
    $queryString = "select * from tblquiz where qstatus=$status AND  qtopic='$topic[topicname]' AND subtopic='$_POST[subtopic]' AND userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]' LIMIT $start, $limit" ;
    $countString = "select * from tblquiz where qstatus=$status AND  qtopic='$topic[topicname]' AND subtopic='$_POST[subtopic]' AND      userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]'";
       }  // NOTE : THIS QUERY IS WORKING PERFECT

       elseif ($topic !== '' && $subtopic !== '' && $status == '' ) {
    $queryString = "select * from tblquiz where   qtopic='$topic[topicname]' AND subtopic='$_POST[subtopic]' AND userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]' LIMIT $start, $limit" ;
    $countString = "select * from tblquiz where   qtopic='$topic[topicname]' AND subtopic='$_POST[subtopic]' AND userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]'";
       }  // NOTE : THIS QUERY IS WORKING PERFECT


       elseif  ($topic == 100 && $subtopic == '' && $status !== '') {
    $queryString = "select * from tblquiz where qstatus= $status AND userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]' LIMIT $start, $limit" ;
    $countString = "select * from tblquiz where qstatus= $status AND userid='$_SESSION[numericuserid]' ";
     }  **// NOTE : THIS QUERY IS NOT WORKING** 

}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but there is a pretty big chance you have a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerable application right now.

Comment: 99% of the trouble here is caused by not using proper [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to do your query construction. If you used those techniques you will not have problems like this. The way you have it now, it will be sheer *luck* that these queries run at all.

Comment: First of all, it is vary bad practice to keep variables inside double quote instead of closing them, calling the variable, and continuing your code. But on your question, when use use !=== in your code, that looks to see if it is a Boolean. If it is not a Boolean, just use == or !=

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tblquiz where qstatus= '$status'
```

qstatus missing quotes?

Comment: SQL injection and yet again SQL injection

Comment: SQL injection indeed.  In fact, this whole block of code is a cluster, but the question was "why is it not working", and I answered the question.  Obviously this user should brush up on sql safety.

Comment: Just because the question is specific it does not mean that those of us with more knowledge should not pass it on. :-)

Comment: Agreed.  We wouldn't want bobby tables to take the server down when he takes a quiz.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

In your elseif-clause your checking to see that $status is empty, and if it is then set $querystring and $countstring. This means that your trying to query for

```
qstatus= AND
```

This should've generated an SQL-error. It's always a good idea to print out your sql-statements when trying to debug.

Comment: SQL injection and yet again SQL injection

Comment: @Adrian Cornish good point but the question isn't about sanitizing SQL is it?

Comment: True - but it is exactly the reason Sony got hacked by Lulzsec. The fact is that is PHP so the OP should be made aware - ask Sony if they think their system was secure. The OP is taking untrusted values directly from HTTP requests - it needs to be mentioned

Comment: hi guys please compare  $queryString  2  and $queryString 4